# Cannot restore duplicity backup

Tags: backup-restoration, duplicity

I've created a backup of my home folder, to a remote system, using duplicity 0.6.26:

`duplicity --no-compression --no-encryption . scp://...`

while being in the home folder.

Now I seem to be unable to restore the backup. I've copied everything from the remote server to a local directory, and I've got a files that look like:

```
$ ls
duplicity-full-signatures.20151002T175740Z.sigtar
duplicity-full.20151002T175740Z.vol280.difftar
duplicity-full.20151002T175740Z.vol141.difftar
duplicity-full.20151002T175740Z.manifest
duplicity-full.20151002T175740Z.vol281.difftar
duplicity-full.20151002T175740Z.vol142.difftar
...
```

I can list the contents of the backup:

```
$ duplicity list --no-encryption --no-compression file:///Users/user/Backup/
Local and Remote metadata are synchronized, no sync needed.
Last full backup date: Fri Oct  2 20:57:40 2015
Fri Oct  2 20:57:38 2015 .
Fri Oct 17 21:01:31 2014 .CFUserTextEncoding
Fri Oct  2 20:19:07 2015 .DS_Store
Fri May 22 09:13:51 2015 .PyCharm40
Fri May 22 10:30:21 2015 .PyCharm40/restart
Wed May 13 19:15:04 2015 .PyCharm40/restart/restarter
Fri Oct  2 20:45:37 2015 .Trash
...
```

but when trying to restore, I get "`No files found in archive - nothing restored.`"

```
$ duplicity restore --no-encryption --no-compression file:///Users/user/Backup/ /tmp/P
Local and Remote metadata are synchronized, no sync needed.
Last full backup date: Fri Oct  2 20:57:40 2015
No files found in archive - nothing restored.
```

What can I do to recover the files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the `.difftar` files were compressed after all. Restoring worked after renaming them to `.difftar.gz`. Must be a bug in duplicity.

Comment: Unknown answer si correct, and I had to rename also .sigtar as .sigtar.gz I had this issue on ubuntu trusty while using "--no-compression --no-encryption".
This is definitely an awfull bug.

Comment: In 2023 am also facing this issue, duplicity is able to list the file I need to restore but says: not found in archive - no files restored. the file I need to restore is a QEMU disk image quite big. Is the rename still a valid solution?